# Which connector(linked services) to use in ADF to connect and execute existing ABAP program

Tags: abap, azure-data-factory, sapconnect

I would like to establish the connection and execute the existing SAP ABAP program using AZURE DATA FACTORY.

Could any one please help me any leads. Appreciate your effort. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you can't do it directly. You must create RFC FM in SAP which run program and call that RFC FM from Azure.
This custom function module must have an interface implemented (import, export, tables) that's similar to /SAPDS/RFC_READ_TABLE2.
Then you set it's name in *customRfcReadTableFunctionModule* parameter.

See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-table?tabs=data-factory&source=docs#create-custom-function-module)

Comment: Thanks for your response Alezhu.  I am not much familiar in SAP let me try your suggestion.